# Create DataObject from Shell Run / Help (MFC C++)

Tags: mfc, drag-and-drop, startmenu, idataobject

I need help to create an IDataObject to enable drag and drop of these 2 Items (Run and Help)
For Example I need to do just like Windows Startmenu does.

to run them I use these

```
CComPtr<IShellDispatch2> pShellDisp;
if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Shell,NULL,CLSCTX_SERVER,IID_IShellDispatch2,(void**)&pShellDisp)))
{
    pShellDisp->Help();    //Help
    pShellDisp->FileRun(); //Run
}
```

Can you guys help me out ?

PS: I need the drag with image Icons too

EDIT [SOLVED]

```
IShellFolder* desk = NULL;
                HRESULT hr =SHGetDesktopFolder(&desk);
                LPITEMIDLIST pidl2=NULL;
                ULONG cbEaten;
                DWORD dwAttribs = 0 ;

                hr = desk->ParseDisplayName(NULL,
                                             NULL,
                                             L"shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}",
                                             &cbEaten,  // This can be NULL
                                             &pidl2,
                                             &dwAttribs);
                hr = desk->GetUIObjectOf(parentHwnd, 1,
                        (PCITEMID_CHILD*)&pidl2, IID_IDataObject, 0, (LPVOID *)lpdataObj);

                desk->Release();
                return;
```

for run:

```
shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587526/c-mfc-create-ishellitem-from-clsid-guid from the same user...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want one of those items in the data object at any point in time, in that case:

- If you already have a IShellItem then you can call `IShellItem::BindToHandler(...,BHID_DataObject,...)`.
- If you [only have the pidl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626934/3501) you can use [SHCreateDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CIDLData_CreateFromIDArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you want to drag&drop both items in the same operation then things get hard. I don't know if both of those objects have the same parent. If they do then even the old CIDLData_CreateFromIDArray can handle it. If they don't then you could try SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists and then use `IShellItemArray::BindToHandler(...,BHID_DataObject,...)`. To support < Vista I believe you have to create your own [CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST) and add it to the dataobject.

Drag images are not really related to this and should be asked in a separate question where you include information about your IDragSourceHelper etc.

Comment: The problem is... I dont have pidl or IShellItem for those items