# How to get a PIDL from a Windows library's GUID?

Tags: c++, windows, guid

How can I get the PIDL of a library from its GUID?

For example, if I have the GUID of the Documents library ("{7B0DB17D-9CD2-4A93-9733-46CC89022E7C}"), how can I convert that into the library's ID list?

I thought `SHParseDisplayName` would do the job, but it returns "file not found."

Bear in mind that what I need is the PIDL of the library, not of its default folder.

This is straight C++, no .Net.

TIA

Edit: This is the code that works, from the response below (without error checks). `guid` is a GUID string prepended with 'shell:::', e.g., 'shell:::{7B0DB17D-9CD2-4A93-9733-46CC89022E7C}'.

```
IShellFolder* pDesktop;
LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktop);
pDesktop->ParseDisplayName(nullptr, nullptr, guid, nullptr, &pidl, 0);
```

Edit 2: Even easier: `SHParseDisplayName` works if the 'shell:::' is prepended:

```
SHParseDisplayName(guid, nullptr, &pidl, 0, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775090(v=vs.85).aspx) you can simply pass it a filename in the form `::{GUID}` if you are using the desktop folder.

Edit: the documentation appears to be incomplete, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626934/5987) you need to add `shell:` to the start of the string.

```
p->ParseDisplayName(m_hWnd, NULL, _T("shell:::{7B0DB17D-9CD2-4A93-9733-46CC89022E7C}"), NULL, &pidl, NULL);
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works when you add 'shell:::'. I understand that the syntax depends on the implementation of the particular interface, but still, MS could have been more helpful on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want the function [**SHGetKnownFolderIDList**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762187(v=vs.85).aspx).

- Given a **KnownFolderID** guid (e.g. [**FOLDERID_DocumentsLibrary**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx)  - `{7B0DB17D-9CD2-4A93-9733-46CC89022E7C}`)
- returns you the [absolute pidl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shtypes/ns-shtypes-_itemidlist) of that KNOWNFOLDER

For example:

```
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderItem(FOLDERID_DocumentsLibrary, 0, NULL, out pidl);
```

### Bonus Chatter

There are three shell functions for dealing with KNOWNFOLDERs

- **[SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx)** : Get the full path of a known folder *(e.g. `C:\Users\Chris\Documents`)*
- **[SHGetKnownFolderIDList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762187(v=vs.85).aspx)**: Get the absolute pidl of a known folder
- **[SHGetKnownFolderItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**: Get the **IShellItem** of a known folder